# getting DuplicateFileException while building Apk

Tags: build.gradle

I am getting a `DuplicateFileException` while building Apk. I used the Applogic source code from GitHub to develop a chat app and while building the gradle I got this exception not able to build the apk. I am using Android Studio 3.0 Gradle version 3.3 and Android Plugin version 2.3.3  Build tool version 26.0.2 sdk version API26

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobicomkit.sample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':mobicomkitui') //Note: use this for customization
    compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVJZF.jpg)

Comment: Cleaned up formatting

Answer (score 1):

You cant use the both at a time gradle dependency and imported applozic source code and any one you need to use

Use this in your case you imported source code

```
 compile project(':mobicomkitui') //Note: use this for customization
```

Remove this code from your app build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:5.2'
```